# rename database name in sql server management studio 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a database called "ip_ent_site". And I wanna rename it to "ip_ent_site1" for example.

[image]

I have done right click and rename, it is keeping on failed.
This is the error message:

[image]

Anyone can help?

Comment: @JasonClark - I think your link links back to this page...

Answer (score 51):

That is because there are open transactions. If those transactions can be killed, then this can easily be done with this SQL

```
ALTER DATABASE ip_ent_site
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
sp_rename 'ip_ent_site', 'new_db_name' ,'DATABASE';
GO
ALTER DATABASE new_db_name
SET MULTI_USER
GO
```

Comment: can you explain what each statement does I am very curios to know, Thanks in advance

Comment: The first statement set the DB to single user and kills all open connections and rolls all open transaction back. The second statement renames the DB. The last statement opens the renamed DB for user connections

Comment: Downvoting is fine. But can whoever downvoted, also care to explain, so all of us learn something new?

Comment: When renaming like this my DB.mdf file didn't get renamed and had issues creating another database with the same name.

Answer (score 24):

Before renaming, set the database to single user mode [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms345598.aspx)

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE ip_ent_site
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

Then rename it

```
USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE ip_ent_site
Modify Name = ip_ent_site1
GO
```

And then put it back to multi user mode

```
ALTER DATABASE ip_ent_site1
SET MULTI_USER;
```

Comment: Setting the database to read only isn't necessary if you temporarily set it to single_user instead. Also, you didn't put in script to remove it from being read only!!

Comment: You are right @ErikE. I edited the answer. Good catch.

Answer (score 13):

The reason is because the database has to prevent any other connection/transaction to the db while you are renaming it.

A simple script to get a lock on the db:

```
ALTER DATABASE [ip_ent_site] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ip_ent_site] MODIFY NAME = [ip_ent_site_new]
GO

ALTER DATABASE [ip_ent_site_new] SET MULTI_USER;    
GO
```

Comment: I have been using this query to rename a database, not sure why the answer is not useful.

Comment: This is valid SQL and does the job, except the third statement needs to use the new name . Wonder who downvoted and why.

Answer (score 5):

To enable the ability to

> right click and rename

the DB:

1. Close all query windows
2. Right click & rename DB

Answer (score 1):

This the simplest way to rename Database name. Just make sure you have closed all the query windows before running this command.

EXEC sp_renamedb 'old_Name', 'new_Name'

Comment: Nice one-liner but: `This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Use ALTER DATABASE MODIFY NAME instead.`

Answer (score 1):

Execute below query

USE master;
GO
sp_renamedb @dbname = 'old_name' , @newname =  'new_name'

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't we also change 'Logical File Name' as well?

`ALTER DATABASE [testdb] MODIFY FILE (NAME=N'testdbold ', NEWNAME=N'testdb')
GO
ALTER DATABASE [testdb] MODIFY FILE (NAME=N'testdbold', NEWNAME=N'testdb_log')
GO`

Answer (score 1):

OFFLINE DATABASE

```
USE [master];
GO
--Disconnect all existing session.
ALTER DATABASE Datatbase_Name SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
```

--Change database in to OFFLINE mode.
ALTER DATABASE Datatbase_Name SET OFFLINE
To rename Physical Database Files, use Open SQL Server Management Studio Folder or use the script below

-- To allow advanced options to be changed.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE
GO
-- To enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Rename MDF FILE dan Log

```
ALTER DATABASE [Datatbase_Name] MODIFY FILE (Name='Old_Mdf_file_Name', FILENAME='C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLMS2016\MSSQL\DATA\New_Mdf_file_Name.mdf')
ALTER DATABASE [Datatbase_Name] MODIFY FILE (Name='Old_log_file_Name', FILENAME='C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLMS2016\MSSQL\DATA\New_log_file_Name.ldf')

EXEC xp_cmdshell 'RENAME "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLMS2016\MSSQL\DATA\Old_Mdf_file_Name.mdf", "New_Mdf_file_Name.mdf"'
GO

EXEC xp_cmdshell 'RENAME "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLMS2016\MSSQL\DATA\Old_log_file_Name.ldf", "New_log_file_Name.ldf"'
GO
ONLINE DATABASE

ALTER DATABASE [Datatbase_Name] SET ONLINE
Go
ALTER DATABASE [Datatbase_Name] SET MULTI_USER
Go
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute system procedure `sp_who2` to find out sessions which use the database and then close applications or kill sessions with [kill](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173730.aspx) command.

Answer (score 0):

Rename SQLDatabase name Using Query

use [master]
go

Alter Database Old_database_name Modify name = New_database_name

or

sp_renameDB 'old_dbname' , 'new_dbname'

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,it will work.

ALTER DATABASE GWPRD_CMCC  --old db name

```
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

GO
ALTER DATABASE GWPRD_CMCC --old db name

```
MODIFY NAME = GWPRD_CMCC_1 --new db name
```

GO
ALTER DATABASE GWPRD_CMCC_1 --new db name
    SET MULTI_USER
GO